# "didn't" vs. "didn't make it"

Tags: word-usage

One of my friends asked me about another friend Jim yesterday, I said

> Jim thought he could get a promotion this year but he **didn't**.

Should I have said this?

> Jim thought he could get a promotion this year but he **didn't make it**.

In fact, Jim did his best to get a promotion, but unfortunately his competitor did better.

Which one is more clear and natural?

Are there any other expressions more natural could be used for the situation?

Comment: Both are clear and natural. The first is neutral; the second implies that it was an effort, or a challenge. For me _he didn't get it_ would be more natural than _he didn't make it_.

Comment: In AmE, *He didn't make it,* can also imply someone has died.  I would use *didn't make it* in situations where some type of deadline or limit is not met.  *Jim tried to get the store before it closed but he didn't make it [in time].*  *Alice thought she would live to be 100 years-old but she didn't make it [to that age].*  As Colin suggests, *didn't get it,* is easier to understand in your example. Jim is not **making** a promotion; Jim is **getting** a promotion.

Answer (score 1):

Without saying "he didn't make it", your example doesn't make sense.

Consider a different example to yours:

> He thought he put his keys in his pocket, but he didn't.

Here, it is very clear that he *didn't* put his keys in his pocket. Either he **did**, or he **didn't**.

Your example uses the word "could", the opposite of which would be "*couldn't*", so you could say:

> Jim thought he *could* get a promotion this year but he *couldn't*.

It seems like your example is trying to say that Jim did not receive a promotion, not that it wasn't *possible* for him. So, you need to say:

> Jim thought he could get a promotion this year but he didn't make it.